# Calculating height of a viewpoint given 3 angles of depression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can not solve this problem I can help

[image: Problem]

---

**English Translation:**

From the top of a hill, a person finds the angles of depression of three consecutive kilometer markers on a straight road to be $\alpha, \beta,$ and $\gamma$. Show that the height $h$ of the hill is:

Comment: Could you translate this...

Comment: From the top of a hill a person finds three consecutive angles Depression stones and indicator of kilometers of a straight road level are α, β and γ. Show That the height h of the hill is:
h=.....

Comment: I spent a while solving this, so I'm trying to help fix the question's problems

Comment: Oh, and, OP, this site isn't a homework-help site. Next time show how you've attempted to solve the problem already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if I understood correctly, it's like this:

Person is standing on top of the hill, at point $A$, looking down at the points $X,Y,Z$ on the ground, each 1 km apart from each other. Draw a line  from $A$ ($\overline{AO}$) perpendicular to the ground -- this is the height $h$ we should find.

[image]

Note that the stones ($X,Y,Z$) marking the kilometers are *not* in the same vertical plane as where the person is standing ($A$)!

We know that:

- $\angle AXO = \alpha$
- $\angle AYO = \beta$
- $\angle AZO = \gamma$
- $\overline{XY} = \overline{YZ} = 1$ km

Then, we know that $\overline{XO}=h\cot{\alpha}$, and likewise $\overline{YO}=h\cot{\beta}$ and $\overline{ZO}=h\cot{\gamma}$.

This was the less intuitive part -- using [Appolonius' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27_theorem), we get that

$$\begin{align*} \overline{XO}^2+\overline{ZO}^2&=2(\overline{YO}^2+\overline{XY}^2)\\
h^2\cot^2{\alpha}+h^2\cot^2{\gamma} &= 2(h^2\cot^2{\beta} + 1\,\mathrm{km}^2)\\
h^2(\cot^2{\alpha}+\cot^2{\gamma}-2\cot^2{\beta})&= 2\,\mathrm{km}^2\\
h^2&=\frac{2\,\mathrm{km}^2}{\cot^2{\alpha}+\cot^2{\gamma}-2\cot^2{\beta}}\\
h&=\sqrt{\frac{2\,\mathrm{km}^2}{\cot^2{\alpha}+\cot^2{\gamma}-2\cot^2{\beta}}}\\
&=\frac{(1)\mathrm{km}\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{{\cot^2{\alpha}+\cot^2{\gamma}-2\cot^2{\beta}}}}\\
&=\frac{1000\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{{\cot^2{\alpha}+\cot^2{\gamma}-2\cot^2{\beta}}}}\,\mathrm{m}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks , thanks for your time.